# Angular build files project port change 8080 port

Tags: angular

I created angular build files using 'ng serve' command. I run that project using below command
[image]

command 'http-server dist/locker-frontend'. currently project run in the browser as
'http://localhost:8080/#/'. Problem is my backend project also run in '8080' port.

Now i need to run my build files in different port. How i change  the port and run angular build files

Comment: Read this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server. Use a different port.

Answer (score 0):

You specify a port by running the --port command  `ng serve --o --port 4200`

Comment: i am talking about angular build files. not angular project